# Darken Filter to image in python (8.7.10 Darken Filter codehs)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I am trying to write a darken_filter and a change_picture function that modifies the pixels in the left half of the image to be darker. Help is much appreciated. Here is my current code:

```
# Constants for the image
IMAGE_URL = "https://codehs.com/uploads/e07cd01271cac589cc9ef1bf012c6a0c"
IMAGE_WIDTH = 280
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 200
DARKENING_FACTOR = 50
MIN_PIXEL_VALUE = 0

image = Image(IMAGE_URL)
image.set_position(70, 70)
image.set_size(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)
add(image)

# This function should take a pixel and return a tuple
# with the new color
def darken_filter(pixel):
    pass

# This function should loop through each pixel on the
# left hand side and call the darken filter to calculate 
# the new color then update the color.
def change_picture():
    pass            

# Give the image time to load
print("Making Darker....")
print("Might take a minute....")
timer.set_timeout(change_picture, 1000)
```

Comment: in this community we don't do the work for you, we help you to solve problem, so have you tried something in your two function or you only asked it ?

Comment: What is the question though? You say _"function should take a pixel"_ but you don't define to us what your "pixel" is (_eg:_ is it a hex RGB value? an integer?, an array?, a tuple?). Do you know about using `For` loops to check pixel values?

Answer (score 0):

Using PILLOW split your image in half

use [class PIL.ImageEnhance.Brightness(image)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageEnhance.html) from The ImageEnhance module that, contains a number of classes that can be used for image enhancement

class PIL.ImageEnhance.Brightness(image):

'Adjust image brightness.

This class can be used to control the brightness of an image. An enhancementfactor of 0.0 gives a black image. A factor of 1.0 gives the original image.'

recompose your image

cant really solve the half-size image maybe it better to split your question in two questions, but I tried the darken filter part for a putative image code below using PIL.ImageEnhance.Brightness(image), Image.point() as found on the web and an attempt to your method, I am sure there is a more straightforward way in the third method but I am a newbie too and probably missing something:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Feb  6 16:38:32 2021

@author: Pietro

"""

from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

import numpy as np

image_input = Image.open('Immagine_6.tif')

image_input.show()

print(image_input.size)
print(image_input.mode)

image_input = image_input.convert('RGB')

# method one from https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/216419/darken-lighten-an-image-python
# Image.point() : https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=image.point#PIL.Image.Image.point
image_output =image_input.point(lambda p: p * 0.5)

image_output.show()


# method two using ImageEnhance module of pillow
# https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageEnhance.html#PIL.ImageEnhance.Brightness
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image_input)

image_output_2 = enhancer.enhance(0.1)

image_output_2.show()

# method three your method sure there is a better way than this one 
# This function should take a pixel and return a tuple
# with the new color
def darken_filter(pixel):
            pixel = (0.3*np.array(pixel)).astype('int')
            pixel = tuple(pixel[0:3])
            return pixel

image_input_dark = image_input.copy()

for x in range(image_input_dark.size[0]):
    for y in range(image_input_dark.size[1]):
        i = image_input_dark.getpixel((x,y))
        ii = darken_filter(i)
        image_input_dark.putpixel((x,y),ii)
    
image_input_dark.show()
```

sample image

[image: sample image]